# Como abrir la galería programáticamente con un Intent en Android?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un botón y quiero que al darle click se abra la galería, hasta ahora solo he cargado otros activities de la siguiente forma:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainSignUp.class );
       startActivity(i);
```

Pero es de clases que tengo en mi proyecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los `Intent` que usas hasta ahora son `Intent` para abrir una actividad concreta. Lo que necesitas para abrir la galería es un `Intent` para solicitar una clase de acción, en este caso `ACTION_VIEW`. Por supuesto vas a tener que declarar que tipo de elemento quieres mostrar:

```
Intent i = new Intent(); // nuevo Intent  
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); // clase de acción  
i.setType("image/*"); // a que tipo de datos queremos aplicar la acción?
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // queremos un task nuevo
startActivity(i); // ¡y dale!
```

El tipo se refiere al *mime type* del contenido, así si quieres abrir la galería por defecto para videos, usas `"video/*"` en vez de image.

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias formas por ejemplo:

**a)**

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); //Define Intent.
intent.setType("image/*"); //Define mime type para abrir imagenes
startActivity(intent); //Abre galería.
```

**b)** También se puede de esta forma accediendo al directorio de las imágenes:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));
startActivity(intent); //Abre galería.
```

**c)** y esta forma usando `Intent.createChooser()` :

```
private static int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
...
...
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);
```